# Column count of is null plus count of is not null do not add up

Tags: mysql, mariadb

Trying to see what's in a column I ended up doing some counting.

The table has 3981 rows.

But the counted column only shows a much lower number in total of its null and non null values.

How come ?

```
MariaDB [mydb]> select count(naf) from client where naf is not null;
+------------+
| count(naf) |
+------------+
|         83 |
+------------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)

MariaDB [mydb]> select count(naf) from client where naf is null;
+------------+
| count(naf) |
+------------+
|          0 |
+------------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)

MariaDB [mydb]> select count(*) from client;
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|     3981 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following query is misleading you:

```
select count(naf) from client where naf is null;
```

The `COUNT` function *ignores* all `NULL` values.  Hence, this query would never return any value other than zero.  In reality, there are 3898 `NULL` records in the `client` table.  To count nulls, you can try using the `SUM` function instead:

```
SELECT SUM(1) FROM client WHERE naf IS NULL;
```

This should be returning a sum of 3898.